# getting error of cannot read properties of null (reading 'addeventlistener') for js

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked line by line and I can not seem to see the issue, it said that somewhere the click event is not clicking anything because its value is null. I need a new set of eyes on this who can maybe spot the issue.

In short, I can click the add task button but for some reason, the edit button is not working. I know why the delete button is not working and that is due to the fact there is not code for it to return yet.

I also put the HTML head in so you can see my js file is there with a defer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-do App</title>
    <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="js/dateTime.js" defer></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<main>
    <section class="task-list">
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
      <div id="tasks">
        <!--<button class = "sort">Sort</button>
            
              <div class="task">
                      <div class="content">
                          <input 
                              type="text" 
                              class="text" 
                              value="A new task"
                              readonly>
                      </div>
                      <div class="actions">
                          <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                          <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                      </div>
                  </div> -->
  
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
```

```js
/************************************
 * creates an object of elements needed *
 ************************************/
 
 const elements = {
    form: document.querySelector("#new-task-form"),
    input: document.querySelector("#new-task-input"),
    list: document.querySelector("#tasks"),
    cal: document.querySelector("#calendar")
}

/****************************
 * Generates an ID for task *
 ****************************/

 const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${new Date().getTime()}`


/**********************************************
 * function that creates the HTML elements *
 **********************************************/

 const createTask = () => {
    const id = createId()
    const task = elements.input.value;
    const date = elements.cal.value;

    if(!task && !date) return alert("Please fill in task and select date");
    if(!task) return alert("Please fill in task");
    if(!date) return alert("Please select date");

    const tasks = document.createElement("div");

    tasks.innerHTML = `
    <button class = "sort">Sort</button>
    <div class="task" date-id = "${id}">
        <div class="content">
            <input type ="checkbox" class="tick">
            <input type ="text" class = "text" id = "text" readonly>${task}
            <label class = "due-date" for ="text">${date}</label>
            <input type ="date" class = "date" id = "date">
        </div>

        <div class = "actions">
            <button class="edit" data-id="${id}">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete" data-id="${id}">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `

    elements.list.appendChild(tasks)
    return tasks
}

/**************************************************************
 * Event that listens for the submit, edit and delete button  *
 **************************************************************/

 elements.list.addEventListener('click',event => {
    const {target} = event;

    const {id} = target.dataset
    const task = id ? document.querySelector('[data-id="${id}"]'):null;
    
    const type = {
        edit: event.target.classList.contains('edit'),
        delete: event.target.classList.contains('delete')
    }

    const isFromSaveLabel = target.innerText.toLowerCase() === 'save'

    if(task && type.edit && isFromSaveLabel){
        const text = task.querySelector('text')
        target.innerText = 'Edit'
        text.addAttribute('readonly')
        return
    };

    if(task && type.edit){
        const text = task.querySelector('text')
        target.innerText = 'save'
        text.removeAttribute('readonly')
        text.focus()
        return
    };

    if(task && type.delete){
        return
    }
    
});

const submitHandler = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    createTask();
}

elements.form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

Comment: i don't see a task id in your code, it is a class

Comment: I don't see any element with id `new-task-form` thus `elements.form` will be undefined. But nonetheless you are trying to add an eventlistener

Comment: the id ```new-task-form``` is there it is in the class header in the HTML file